# Redirecting back after login in PHP

Tags: php

I have a scenario like this. When the admin receive a mail from client about orders with a URL link to PHP form page, which only can accessed by admin login. If administrator is not logged in, the url will be redirected to the login page. After the administrator logged in successfully I need to redirect him to the URL that he received in the email.

Can anybody tell me how to do it. I read something about HTTP_REFERER, but its not working properly as if the admin is not logged in, it directly redirect to login.php

Please help me to solve the problem

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try to give some example here:

**originating_page.php**

```
if(!is_admin) {
    $_SESSION["originatingpage"] = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].'/login.php');
  }
}
```

**login.php**

```
if(is_admin_success_login) {
  if (isset($_SESSION["originatingpage"])) {
    $originatingpage = $_SESSION["originatingpage"];
    unset($_SESSION["originatingpage"]);
    header('Location: http://'.$originatingpage);
  } else {
    //do another default action
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Store the URL of the page the person was trying to access *before* redirecting to login.php. You can store it in a session variable or in the URL. Then your login.php page will know where to send the user after they're logged in.

For example, at the page requiring login:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['came_from'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header("Location: login.php");
```

And in login.php, after the user has been logged in:

```
session_start();
header("Location: http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SESSION['came_from']);
```

Comment: The URL contain dynamic values such as IDs. It can be change anytime, can you please tell me how can I store the URL in a session before the login.php call

Comment: It should be noted though, and not that I did a particularly stellar job in my answer, that the `Location` header should be fully-qualified (this means the `http://host.com` in addition to the extended `/path/to/script.php?args`)

Answer (score -1):

your login page can have a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>" />
```

Or in the "originating page, you can pass the current REQUEST_URI as a get variable, which in turn goes in to that same form element. Then when they submit the form you check for `$_REQUEST['redirect_to']` and pass it off with a `header()`.

```
...
if (logged in && redirect to is filled in){
  header('Location: '.$_REQUEST['redirect_to']);
}
...
```

*Above is pseudo-code, btw*